# How to initialize the LiveData in ViewModel for the first time in android? and which factory to use?

Tags: android, viewmodel

I want to initialize the LiveData value when the app is launched, not every time the orientation changes.
Can I use the constructor of the subclass of ViewModel for it?

Comment: If you are using kotlin, here is another approach: https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9#gistcomment-3245478

Comment: @aminography I just tried to initialize them in onCreate itself after checking for null. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `LiveData` which pushes the last value to observers for every config change (like a RxJava `BehaviourSubject`), you should use something which pushes the event once.

You can use:

- `SingleLiveEvent`: Send the event to only 1 observer, check [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java) and [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) or alternatives [here](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9)
- `LiveEvent`: Send the event to all the observers, check [here](https://github.com/hadilq/LiveEvent)

Both of those approaches will not cache events, which means that an observer should be already observing the `*LiveEvent` to receive it

You can find articles online about alternative approaches but the philosophy behind them is probably the same

Comment: I just tried to initialize them in onCreate itself after checking for null. Thanks for your help.